# Return floats from fragmentshader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

For an application I need to create a depth-image of a mesh. Basically I want a image, where each pixel tells the distance between the camera center and the intersection point. I choose to do this task with OpenGL, so that most of the computation can be done on the GPU instead of the CPU.

Here is my code for the vertex-shader. It computes the real-world coordinate of the intersection point and stores the coordinates in a `varying vec4`, so that I have access to it in the fragment-shader.

```
varying vec4 verpos;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    verpos = gl_ModelViewMatrix*gl_Vertex;
}
```

And here the code for the fragment-shader. In the fragment-shader I use these coordinates to compute the eulidean distance to the origin (0,0,0) using pythagoras. To get access to the computed value on the CPU, my plan is to store the distance as a color using `gl_FragColor`, and extract the color values using `glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &distances[0]);`

```
varying vec4 verpos;
void main() 
{ 
    float x = verpos.x;
    float y = verpos.y;
    float z = verpos.z;

    float depth = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z) / 5000.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(depth, depth, depth, 1.0);
}
```

The problem is, that I receive the results only in the precision of `0.003921569` (`=1/255`). 
The resulting values contain for instance `0.364705890, 0.364705890, 0.364705890, 0.364705890, 0.368627459, 0.368627459, 0.368627459`. Most of the values in a row are exactly the same, and then there is a jump of 1/255. 
So somewhere inbetween `gl_FragColor` and `glReadPixels` OpenGL converts the floats to 8 bits and afterwards converts them back to float.

How can I extract distance-values as float without loosing precision?

Comment: You're writing to the backbuffer which is 8bit RGBA, if you want to write float values, you need to render to a `FrameBufferObject` with a `HALF_FLOAT` or `FLOAT` texture attached to it, then read from that texture.

Comment: Why that factor of 1/5000 for the depth? Why are you not using the readily available `length` built-in function, i.e. `length(verpos)`. Technically you could even save you the step of writing the depth to the fragment color (and disable color writes alltogether) and just read the contents of depth buffer and linearize the 1/x mapping of the depth values therein. The depth buffer will have at least 16 bits, more likely 24 bits. Technically you can even write the linear depth to the depth buffer, but that impacts performance.

Comment: @datenwolf I divide by 5000, so that the value is in the range `[0, 1]`.

Comment: And I don't use the depth buffer, because you don't recieve the the depth to the center, but to the viewing plane.

Comment: @user38034: In OpenGL there is no such thing as a "center", there is just "some" space OpenGL knows nothing about and there are clip and NDC space which is what OpenGL operates in. And the vertex shader is mapping from this "some" space to clip space (and from there some hardwired transformation into NDC space). The depth buffer operates in NDC space and nothing else. And for what it's worth there's no practical difference in distance to view plane vs. distance to origin; it boils down to a constant offset.

Comment: @user38034: And you can write arbitrary values to the depth buffer with `gl_FragDepth = …` and you could easily plug your depth value therein.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a R32F or R16F texture to a [FBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) and render to it. Then extract the pixels with `glGetTexImage2D()` like you would do with `glReadPixels()`.